# Pastry sheets - storing, packing & shipping

Tags: storage-lifetime, gluten-free, puff-pastry

I am trying out some puff pastry sheets for a couple of my friends in a different city who are visiting us.. it takes minimum 10 hrs for them to reach their place (road and air travel included).. I have to pack the pastry sheets for them to take when they leave and they will be storing it in freezer/ refrigerator for future use - I would like to know :

1. How should I pack the sheets considering that the pastry dough (stored in freezer at my end) would be at room temp for 10 continuous hrs.
2. Will the temperature fluctuations affect the product?
3. Or should I make it fresh the day they leave and pack it at room temperature?
4. Is it safe for gluten-free ones to remain at room temp for that long?